# What are the steps to launching a Safemoon clone on PancakeSwap?

Tags: bsc, pancakeswap

I have created a contract on bsc mainnet and sent half the token supply to pancakeswap liquidity.

What are the remaining steps, in detail, that need to be accomplished on my end in order to ensure a fair and balanced token launch?

Comment: I half of the tokens are already in a liquidity pool (available for purchase), then you have launch already, haven't you?